# FullCalendar agenda week view by day

Tags: fullcalendar

Is is possible to create a view like attached using the fullcalendar scheduler?  Basically group by day.  Like showed in the images below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by creating a custom view.  The key is a type of timelineWeek and slotDuration of 24:00

```
views: {
          timeline7Days: {
          type: 'timelineWeek',
          slotDuration: '24:00',
          duration: { days: 7 },
           buttonText: 'resource week'
        }
```

Comment: You don´t close this one: timeline7Days: {